# Net has multiple drivers (Verilog)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I've looked at some other forums and know that this type of error occurs when multiple outputs drive the same input however I am struggling to see how to fix this error and what specifically is causing it within my code. For context, the code that I am attaching is a submodule that is instantiated in a top traffic light controller module. The purpose of this module is to control what state the traffic light controller is in (Green_red, yellow_red, red_green, and red_yellow). The code that I wrote works when I simulate it with a testbench, however, I keep getting the same errors. There are two other submodules that have the same errors that I didn't attach, however, they follow the same exact logic as the car module just for the different inputs.

This is my code for the top module:

```
module Controller (clk, rst, c, e, p, SCL, SVL, current);
    input  clk, rst, c, e, p; //Clock, reset, and sensors
    output reg [2:0] SCL, SVL; //Lights for Santa Clara and Seventh. 100 is green, 010 is yellow, and 001 is red
    output reg [1:0] current; //Current state

wire [1:0] c_current, e_current, p_current;
wire c_served, e_served, p_served;
wire c_begin, e_begin, p_begin; 

wire [2:0] f_reset; //Forced reset for when multiple sensors are detected at same time. 100 is for car, 010 is for emg, 001 is for ped
reg [2:0] forced;

assign f_reset = forced;

parameter SCG_SVR = 2'b00, // Santa Clara green, Seventh red
          SCY_SVR = 2'b01, // Santa Clara yellow, Seventh red
          SCR_SVG = 2'b10, // Santa Clara red, Seventh green
          SCR_SVY = 2'b11; // Santa Clara red, Seventh yellow

initial //Default conditions
    begin
        current = SCG_SVR; 
        SCL = 3'b100;
        SVL = 3'b011;
    end

Car carl (clk, rst, c, c_begin, c_served, c_current, f_reset);
Emergency emg1 (clk, rst, e, e_begin, e_served, e_current, f_reset);
Pedestrian ped1 (clk, rst, p, p_begin, p_served, p_current, f_reset);

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (c_begin && ~e_begin) //Car has 2nd priority, occurs whenever emergency is not detected
        begin
            current = c_current;
            forced = 3'b011;
        end
    else if (p_begin && ~e_begin && ~c_begin) //Pedestrian has least priority, occurs whenever emergency and car aren't detected
        begin
            current = p_current;
            forced = 3'b110;
        end    
    else if (e_begin) //Emergency has the most priority
        begin
            current = e_current;
            forced = 3'b101;
        end
    else
        begin
            current = SCG_SVR; //Current state whenever nothing is detected
            forced = 3'b111;
        end
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (c_served || e_served || p_served) forced = 3'b000;
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    case(current)
        SCG_SVR: 
            begin
                SCL = 3'b100; //Santa Clara green
                SVL = 3'b001; //Seventh red
            end        
        SCY_SVR: 
            begin
                SCL = 3'b010; //Santa Clara yellow
                SVL = 3'b001; //Seventh red
            end        
        SCR_SVG: 
            begin
                SCL = 3'b001; //Santa Clara red
                SVL = 3'b100; //Seventh green
            end        
        SCR_SVY: 
            begin
                SCL = 3'b001; //Santa Clara red
                SVL = 3'b010; //Seventh yellow
            end
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

This is my code for the sub module:

```
module Car (clk, rst, c_reqd, c_beg, c_srvd, current_state, f_reset);
    input clk, rst, c_reqd; //Clock, reset, car requested
    input wire [2:0] f_reset;
    output reg c_srvd = 0, c_beg = 0; //Car served, car began
    output reg [1:0] current_state;

reg [1:0] next_state;

assign forced = f_reset;

parameter SCG_SVR = 2'b00, // Santa Clara green, Seventh red
          SCY_SVR = 2'b01, // Santa Clara yellow, Seventh red
          SCR_SVG = 2'b10, // Santa Clara red, Seventh green
          SCR_SVY = 2'b11; // Santa Clara red, Seventh yellow

integer counter = 0;

initial //Default condition
    begin
        next_state = SCG_SVR;        
    end

always @(*)
begin: CFSM_seq
    if (rst || f_reset[2] == 1)
        begin
            next_state = SCG_SVR;
            counter = 0;
        end
    else current_state = next_state;
end

always @ (posedge clk)
begin: CFSM_comb
    case(current_state)
        SCG_SVR:
            begin
                if (c_reqd)
                    begin
                        next_state = SCY_SVR;
                        c_srvd = 0;
                        c_beg = 1;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        next_state = SCG_SVR;
                        c_srvd = 0;
                        c_beg = 0;
                    end                     
            end
        SCY_SVR:
            begin
                if (counter < 4)
                    begin
                        next_state = SCY_SVR;
                        counter = counter + 1;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        next_state = SCR_SVG;
                        counter = 0;
                    end
            end            
        SCR_SVG:
            begin
                if (counter < 10)
                    begin
                        next_state = SCR_SVG;
                        counter = counter + 1;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        next_state = SCR_SVY;
                        counter = 0;
                    end
            end        
        SCR_SVY:
            begin
                if (counter < 3)
                    begin
                        next_state = SCR_SVY;
                        counter = counter + 1;
                        if (counter == 1)
                            begin
                                c_srvd = 1;
                            end
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        next_state = SCG_SVR;
                        counter = 0;
                    end
            end        
    endcase                                                                    
end

endmodule
```

And these are some of the errors I'm getting:

````
[Synth 8-6859] multi-driven net on pin carl/next_state[1] with 1st driver pin 'carl/next_state_reg[1]__0/Q' 
[Synth 8-6859] multi-driven net on pin carl/next_state[1] with 2nd driver pin 'carl/next_state_reg[1]/Q' 
[Synth 8-6859] multi-driven net on pin carl/next_state[0] with 1st driver pin 'carl/next_state_reg[0]__0/Q' 
[Synth 8-6859] multi-driven net on pin carl/next_state[0] with 2nd driver pin 'carl/next_state_reg[0]/Q' 
[Synth 8-6859] multi-driven net on pin carl/counter[31] with 1st driver pin 'carl/counter_reg[31]__0/Q' 
[Synth 8-6859] multi-driven net on pin carl/counter[31] with 2nd driver pin 'carl/counter_reg[31]/Q' 
[Synth 8-6859] multi-driven net on pin carl/counter[30] with 1st driver pin 'carl/counter_reg[30]__0/Q' 
[Synth 8-6859] multi-driven net on pin carl/counter[30] with 2nd driver pin 'carl/counter_reg[30]/Q' 

//multiple more of the same errors with car1 and counter[n]
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You modify (drive) `counter` in both always constructs. It seems that first, small always is reset condition trigger, use async reset instead in the second construct, like this (as an example):

```
wire rst_n = ~(rst || (f_reset[2] == 1));

always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
    if(!rst_n) begin
        counter = 0;
    end else begin
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `forced`, `counter`, and `next_state` from two different always blocks. Combine that into one block and it should work.

And you don't need a state where both lights are red at the same time?

Comment: Alas, in the olden days we didn't need to have red in both directions. But you are right, it would greatly reduce the carnage at rush hour.